# How can I get the Unique ID and MAX(date)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-administration

Could someone help me please. I don't know what wrong with the query I think it's is right..

Item Table
[image: item]

Loan Table
[image: loan]

Pawner Table
[image: pawner]

Loan_assignment Table
[image: loan_assignment]

This is my query for getting the unique ID and MAX(date)

```
SELECT distinct p.pawner_id, c.item_name, c.description, l.net_proceeds, 
max(DATE_FORMAT(a.date_loan_granted, '%d-%b-%Y')) as date 
from pawner p, loan l, collateral c, loan_assignment a, pawnshop b 
WHERE b.pawnshop_id = a.pawnshop_id AND p.pawner_id = a.pawner_id 
AND l.loan_id = a.loan_id AND a.item_id = c.item_id 
AND b.pawnshop_id = 1 group by p.pawner_id;
```

The result of the above^ query is this:
[image]

The result that I like to happen is this below
[image]

Comment: Start by fixing your query so it uses proper explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: select p.pawner_id, c.item_id, c.description, l.net_proceeds,
date_format(max(a.date_loan_granted), '%d-%b-%Y') as date_format
from loan_assignment a
left join pawner p on p.pawner_id = a.pawner_id
left join collateral c on c.item_id = a.item_id
left join loan l on l.loan_id = a.loan_id and l.net_proceeds in (select m
in(net_proceeds) from loan group by loan_id) group by p.pawner_id;

Comment: @GordonLinoff still the output for net amount is wrong idont know why?..

Comment: You still have problems with the query:  (1) You have columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by`.  (2) You are doing a max on a string which is not the same as doing a max on the date.  Do a query to get the maximum time and then join that back in.  It is probably what Brian's answer is.

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments, if you want the highest date_loan_granted value for each pawner_id, and not each (pawner_id, item_id) you might instead want:

```
select m.pawner_id,
       i.item_name,
       i.description,
       l.net_amount,
       date_format(m.date_loan_granted, '%d-%b-%Y') as date_loan_granted
  from (select pawner_id,
               max(loan_id) as loan_id,
               max(date_loan_granted) as date_loan_granted
          from loan_assignment
         group by pawner_id) m
  join loan_assignment la
    on m.pawner_id = la.pawner_id
   and m.loan_id = la.loan_id
   and m.date_loan_granted = l.date_loan_granted
  join loan l
    on m.loan_id = l.loan_id
  join item i
    on la.item_id = i.item_id
```

Comment: I have executed your query but it shows that it has more data. I just want to get the the max date and least net amount and group them by pawner_id.. thanks for the help

Comment: The above query should provide the expected output for the sample data that you actually posted. It shows the info associated with the latest loan granted for each pawner and item. Perhaps you want the highest date for each pawner, not each (pawner, item) combination. Even if that is the case though, I don't understand when you say "least net amount". The net amount on the latest date might not be the least net amount.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct p.pawner_id, c.item_name, c.description, l.net_proceeds, 
DATE_FORMAT(MAX(a.date_loan_granted), '%d-%b-%Y') as date 
from pawner p, loan l, collateral c, loan_assignment a, pawnshop b 
WHERE b.pawnshop_id = a.pawnshop_id AND p.pawner_id = a.pawner_id 
AND l.loan_id = a.loan_id AND a.item_id = c.item_id 
AND b.pawnshop_id = 1 group by p.pawner_id;
```

Comment: Thanks it works.. how can I get the updated Net amount? .. I have learned something today.. "the max function must be inside the date_format.."